# What does a CALL to an address in the .rodata segment do?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have some assembler code here (32-bit, Linux, NASM), and in it, I assume, there is a call into an address which is part of the .rodata segment. I couldn't find information about what this does exactly, or maybe I just interpreted the code wrong.

```
 60000f7:   mov    edx, 0x2
 60000fc:   mov    eax, 0x2

 ;[...] EAX and EDX are not changed

 6000140:   lea    eax, [edx+eax*8]
 6000143:   call   DWORD PTR [eax*4+0x6001000]
```

As far as I understood the code: It sets the EAX register to an address `2 + 2*8 = 18` and then calls the address `18*4 + 0x6001000 = 0x6001048`, which is in the .rodata segment and pointing to a single ASCII character.

But what is the effect of this instruction? Or did I get it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an indirect call.

In `call 0x6001000`, the address to call is an immediate value.

In `call eax`, the address to call is in `eax`.

In `call dword ptr[eax*4+0x6001000]`, the address to call is in `[eax*4+0x6001000]`. The character you saw in .rodata probably was an address.